# YouTube api v3 error : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header... when trying to use CORS

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, google-api, cors

I'm trying to move a video to a playlist and when I tested in [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert), it worked but when trying to use it in my code, it doesn't. This access token is obtained in the same way as Mr. Ibrahim's [CORS Upload sample](https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com/git/yt-upload-javascript/index.html) with added scope as required.

I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. here is my ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
        url:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems',
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            contentType: 'application/json', //I've tried application/jsonp
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'X-JavaScript-User-Agent':'Google APIs Explorer'
            //I've also tried 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
        },
        data:{
            'kind': 'youtube#playlistItem',
            'snippet': {
                'playlistId': playlistId,
                'resourceId': {
                    'kind': 'youtube#video',
                    'videoId': videoId
                }
            }
        },
        error:function(jqXHR){
            console.log('moving item failed' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

EDIT : 
This is the request header from Chrome dev tools which is **NOT** working from my localhost :

`:host:www.googleapis.com
:method:OPTIONS
:path:/youtube/v3/playlistItems
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh;q=0.2,pt;q=0.2
access-control-request-headers:accept, contenttype, x-javascript-user-agent, authorization, content-type
access-control-request-method:POST
cache-control:no-cache
origin:http://localhost
pragma:no-cache
referer:http://localhost/anything/blablala/blablabla/videos/add_videos_content.html
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36`

This is the corresponding response headers :

`alternate-protocol:443:quic
cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-length:0
content-type:application/octet-stream
date:Tue, 06 May 2014 01:50:27 GMT
expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:GSE
status:200 OK
version:HTTP/1.1
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block`

EDIT 2 : This is the working request header when adding vids using test API from developers.google.com:

`:host:content.googleapis.com
:method:POST
:path:/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=myplaylistidthatIpurposelyhide
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ms;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh;q=0.2,pt;q=0.2
authorization:Bearer myrandomaccesstokenthatIpurposelyhide
cache-control:no-cache
content-length:208
content-type:application/json
origin:https://content.googleapis.com
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.PGgChEFan04.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Fz%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAItRSTNppjT6YlqcSUdCS2FO0-uz5FYA6Q
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
x-clientdetails:appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1%3B%20WOW64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F34.0.1847.131%20Safari%2F537.36&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1%3B%20WOW64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F34.0.1847.131%20Safari%2F537.36
x-goog-encode-response-if-executable:base64
x-javascript-user-agent:google-api-javascript-client/1.0.0-alpha
x-origin:https://developers.google.com
x-referer:https://developers.google.com`

This is the corresponding response header

`alternate-protocol:443:quic
cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:490
content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:Wed, 07 May 2014 00:53:35 GMT
etag:"N5Eg36Gl054SUNiWWc-Su3t5O-k/DLbDf5tChxaDDEYTFBRlxLsiJl0"
expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:GSE
status:200 OK
version:HTTP/1.1
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block`

Comment: Can you post the headers sent/received with Fiddler/dev tools?

Comment: @SilverlightFox see my latest EDIT. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - and what are the headers like when you tried the example that worked?

Comment: @SilverlightFox added the working headers from working example from test API in developers.google.com. Thanks!

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be coming from the server to allow a cross domain request. The example that works posts to the same domain as itself so doesn't need it. As you sure you don't have to proxy it via your server?

Comment: @SilverlightFox I don't think I have to...I'm basically doing it the same way as Mr. Ibrahim's CORS example. Just the headers sent aren't the same. Maybe I'll try to compare his headers with mine and see where I've gone wrong. I'm quite busy right now with another project so I'll update you again after awhile.  Thank you for your help! Appreciate it. :)

Comment: CORS is not used in the working headers - it's a same origin request.

Comment: @SilverlightFox you are absolutely right. I didn't realise it. The working one was from Google test API which doesn't use CORS. Should I re-edit the working headers with Mr. Ibrahim's one? However, do take note that his one is uploading file using CORS, not moving a video using CORS.